# Can I reinstall Linux from live USB?

Tags: windows, linux, multi-boot, grub2, liveusb

I just wanna confirm, if I uninstall Linux and have a problem booting Windows XP, I'll still be able to reinstall Linux from my live USB, right? I guess it would reinstall Linux and reinstall Grub2, and I'd be able to access the new Linux as well as Windows XP? Or will I get any errors?

Also, I have another distro on another live USB, will I be able to use that while Grub2 is gone?

Comment: you should rather rebuild grub instead of wiping your linux installation.

Comment: Why don't you test it? Just boot one of your usb sticks. You don't have to follow up on the install routine once the stick has booted. This way you can make sure your usb sticks are bootable, detect your hardware and can boot without problems.

Comment: @Znau, but I'd want to get rid of linux (and grub) for space. I haven't installed yet, but I'm planning to, and I'm just planning ahead for the uninstall in case there's any issues.

Comment: @TorbenF, I've already tested my usb sticks they both boot fine. I'm just inexperienced and not sure if they'd be able to boot after an actual installation has been deleted (since the usb sticks show a grub screen too when they boot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would work, but there are quicker, less aggressive ways to get the same result. Such as reconfiguring grub or the MBR.

Comment: Well, I'm asking just because I'm wondering, if Linux is deleted and the XP MBR is broken by Grub (which is apparently what happens), how am I meant to fix anything if I can't access any OS? That's my biggest fear. And it's not like I have a Windows XP CD that I can boot from to access the Windows Recovery Console. As this is my only computer, I wanna make sure I know what my options are ahead of time.

Comment: Do you have any computer that you could use to create a recovery disc?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: @user219048: As I mentioned in my comment on your previous question, you can use either a Linux or Windows Live CD/USB to repair the XP bootloader.